# Complex integration and theorems

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

If $C$ is a closed path oriented in the positive direction and $$g(z_0)=\int_C \frac{z^3+2z}{(z-z_0)^3}$$
show that $g(z_0)=6\pi iz_0$ when $z_0$ is in interior of $C$ and $g(z_0)=0$ when $z_0$ is out of $C$

I could show the first part, using it
 $$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}$$

anyone can help in the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_0$ lies outside $C$, then the integrand is analytic inside and on $C$. Hence, by Cauchy's theorem, the integral is $0$.

Comment: The theorem that I have in my book is: If a function f is analytic at all interior points and on a closed path C then $\int_C f(z)dz=0$. But this says nothing about the outside.

Comment: The hypotheses of the theorem hold with $f(z) = (z^3 + 2z)/(z - z_0)^3$ when $z_0$ is out of $C$. That was the point.

Comment: If z_0 is outside of C, then the function IS analytic at all interior points and on a closed path C, because z-z_0 will never be zero on any interior point (the denominator).

Comment: I still can not understand. Where is this Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: Cauchy's theorem is exactly what you stated in the first comment.

Comment: @askazy you've stated it.

Comment: I do not know if I understand this correctly, intuitively I think that whenever the point is outside of the region the integrate is 0, but when I read the theorem the impression I have is that the integral is 0 when it is on the boundary or inside, which makes no sense.

Comment: @askazy I'm not sure what you mean. In the problem, to show $g(z_0) = 0$, we use the fact that the integrand is analytic inside and on $C$. It's analytic inside and on $C$ because it's the quotient of two entire functions whose denominator is never zero inside or on $C$. So by the theorem you stated, the integral is zero.